# java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationAssociate ctor not called in same callstack as FacesConfigParser.contextInitialized()

Tags: jsf, websphere

I'm running Java Server Faces on a IBM WebSphere 6.1. I'm getting 
this strange error message when I start the server:

`[2009-07-21 15:49:35:784 CEST] 00000015 ServletWrappe E   SRVE0100E: Did not realize  init() exception thrown by servlet Faces Servlet: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationAssociate ctor not called in same callstack as FacesConfigParser.contextInitialized()`.

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong?

Comment: could you paste the complete stacktrace please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WAS 5.1 did not have a JSF implementation but added Sun JSF 1.0 to WEB-INF/lib.
WAS 6.1 ships Sun JSF 1.1_01 with IBM fixes directly within the server.

Remove the Sun JSF 1.0 from WEB-INF/lib (by following the migration guidelines from RAD7).

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have the different versions of the JSF in both the `WEB-INF/lib` and the `Websphere/lib` and/or the Websphere's classloading policy is been set to "module" instead of "application".